# Impossible to get email from Twitter login

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to get email from twitter login for days. Did everything according to Docs and stack overflow. Still getting the same response, `This user does not have an email address.`. Tried to get the email with 2 methods.

Method 1: (Here json did not contain email)

```
let request = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser().urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"], error: nil)

    TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser().sendTwitterRequest(request, completion: { (response, data, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print(json) // this json did not contain email
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
    })
```

Method 2: (Always gave error saying `This user does not have an email address.`)

```
TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser().requestEmail(forCurrentUser: { (email, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription) // gave output "This user does not have an email address."
        return
    }
    if let email = email {
        print(email)
    }
})
```

Generated new keys multiple times and updated them inside App. Still getting the same error. Android App gets the email without fail using the same key that is used in iOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get user email address, your application should be whitelisted.[Use this form](https://help.twitter.com/forms/platform) . You can either send mail to sdk-feedback@twitter.com with some details about your App like Consumer key, App Store link of an App, Link to privacy policy, Metadata, Instructions on how to log into our App etc..They will respond within 2-3 working days.

After your app is whitelisted, You can use Twitter Framework or API to get email.

Comment: Using the same keys the android app is able to get the email of user. Does twitter have different policy for each platform.

Comment: @BibinJacob the account from which you are logging in, Does the email for that account has been verified(you click link in the mail sent to you and verify)?

Comment: We tried with the same account on both platforms. And the form you have mentioned says developer can directly enable permission from settings which I've already done.

Comment: i got email successfully after my iOS app get whitelisted.

Comment: How does the android app get the email address without the app getting whitelisted.